# mySql JSON string field returns encoded

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

First week having to deal with a MYSQL database and JSON field types and I cannot seem to figure out why values are encoded automatically and then returned in encoded format.

Given the following SQL

```
-- create a multiline string with a tab example
SET @str ="Line One
Line 2  Tabbed out
Line 3";
-- encode it
SET @j = JSON_OBJECT("str", @str);

-- extract the value by name
SET @strOut = JSON_EXTRACT(@J, "$.str");

-- show the object and attribute value.
SELECT @j, @strOut;
```

You end up with what appears to be a full formed JSON object with a single attribute encoded.

```
@j = {"str": "Line One\n\tLine 2\tTabbed out\n\tLine 3"}
```

but using JSON_EXTRACT to get the attribute value I get the encoded version including outer quotes.

```
@strOut = "Line One\n\tLine 2\tTabbed out\n\tLine 3"
```

I would expect to get my original string with the \n \t all unescaped to the original values and no outer quotes. as such

```
Line One
Line 2  Tabbed out
Line 3
```

I can't seem to find any JSON_DECODE or JSON_UNESCAPE or similar functions.

I did find a JSON_ESCAPE() function but that appears to be used to manually build a JSON object structure in a string.

**What am I missing to extract the values to the original format?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) function

```
SET @strOut = JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT(@J, "$.str") );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, browse documentation for 2 hours to not find that myself :)
I'll accept later cause it won't accept so fast.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [handy operator `->>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) for this.

It was introduced in MySQL 5.7.13, and basically combines `JSON_EXTRACT()` and `JSON_UNQUOTE()`:

```
SET @strOut = @J ->> '$.str';
```

Comment: Yep, that's equivalent to `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@J, '$.str'))`

Comment: @BillKarwin: yes, and it is much shorter to write...

Comment: My `SELECT Version()` returns "8.0.17", it doesn't seem to work for me assigning to a variable like that, but it does work in a SELECT like this `SELECT @j, @strOut; @j->>"$.str"`

Answer (score 1):

The result of JSON_EXTRACT() is intentionally a JSON document, not a string.

A JSON document may be:

- An object enclosed in `{ }`
- An array enclosed in `[ ]`
- A scalar string value enclosed in `" "`
- A scalar number or boolean value
- A `null` — but this is not an SQL NULL, it's a JSON `null`. This leads to confusing cases because you can extract a JSON field whose JSON value is `null`, and yet in an SQL expression, this fails `IS NULL` tests, and it also fails to be equal to an SQL string `'null'`. Because it's a JSON type, not a scalar type.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful as I can now see why it returned encoded. That would allow more complex documents to be broken up and manipulated via all the same JSON functions.